# iOS - animation not repeating

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, repeat

I've made something like:

```c
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                 delay:0 
                 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                 animations:^{
                     NSLog(@"Repeating...");
                     /** code **/
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     /** code **/
                 }];
```

But the animation does not repeat itself.
Am I missing something?

---

I've removed the color animation, but the animation doesn't repeat yet. But I must be doing something really wrong, 'cause I tried the following simple code and the animation still doesn't repeat:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f 
                 delay:0
                 options: UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                 animations:^{
                     NSLog(@"Repeating...");
                     self.alpha = 1;
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

Comment: Does the animation occur at least once? If not at all, you might be trying to animate something that is not animatable. Add the missing code so we can see what you're doing, because the code you posted here looks fine.

Comment: Yeah, it executes once and than stops.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the animation (still would like to see your code) you might have to *reverse* your animation in order for it to repeat. For example, if your animation changes an alpha value from 0 to 1, repeating that, without reversing the alpha back to 0, isn't going to do much. You may need to add `UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse` to your animation options.

Comment: I can't really post my code, but I'm trying to animate shapes changing color/size/position. Currently I successfully changed the color and position (using animateWithDuration), but not the size. Additionally, the animation is not repeating, even with the Reverse option.

Comment: Size and position should be reversible. Not sure if color change is reversible. Try reducing your animation to just one thing (size, or position, or color; honestly, try size or position first) and see if it reverses and repeats. You may have to not reply on iOS repeating for you, and instead put your own reverse code in the completion block, and then restart the animation yourself.

Comment: I'm not able to change the size using the setBounds method. What should I use?

Comment: A view's bounds can be animated, as well as its frame, center, transform, alpha, backgroundColor, and contentStretch properties. It may be that if you are trying to animate the view's _color_, that that might be short circuiting the repetition. That's just a guess though. Try removing the color change from your animations and see if that lets the animations repeat.